# Обнаружение утечек памяти

Tags: windows, c++

Чем обычно пользуются, когда ищут утечки памяти в программах на C++ под Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Могу посоветовать Visual Leak Detector, если используете Visual Studio.

Comment: Не умеет находить утечки LocalAlloc и GlobalAlloc

Answer (score 3):

BoundsChecker

Answer (score 3):

Для Visual Studio также можно воспользоваться Debug CRT (crtdbg.h) [Пример](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/cpp/82514/)

Answer (score 2):

Если проект на MFC, полезно заглянуть в MSDN: [обнаружение утечек памяти в MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/c99kz476(v=VS.100).aspx).